# $P\in \beta $ s.t. $PA+PB+PC+PD $ is minim

Tags: geometry, 3d

Let $\alpha, \beta $ two planes s.t. $\alpha || \beta$ and $A, B, C, D\in \alpha $ four distinct points.

Find $P\in \beta $ s.t. $PA+PB+PC+PD $ is minim.